# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '7')

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code is very simple that just to check if CEO_box and Acc_box's checkbox is checked or not, if so, send email to the email address column and set inform_cell as 'informed'.
But I have no idea why I keep getting this error.  It seems like is var courseCol = data[i][7]got some matter, but I can't see any problem with this.

```
function sendEmailver2() {
  try{

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1")
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   
    //msg body sheet
    const templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("template").getRange(1,1).getValue();


    for(var i=2; i <= lr; i++) {
      var CEO_box = sheet.getRange(i, 25);
      var Acc_box = sheet.getRange(i, 26);
      var courseCol = data[i][7]
      var receiverName = data[i][6]
      var receiverEmail = data[i][18]
      var inform_cell = data[i][27]
      var totalAmount = data[i][12]


      if(Acc_box.isChecked() && CEO_box.isChecked() && inform_cell.getValue() =="uninformed") {
        var subject = "please check email"
        var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",receiverName).replace("{courseName}",courseCol).replace("{amountVal}", totalAmount)
        console.log("send Email to:"+ receiverEmail)
        MailApp.sendEmail(receiverEmail, subject, messageBody);
        inform_cell.setValue("informed");
        
      }


    }
  } catch(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e)
  }

}
```

Comment: That error means that `data[i]` is `undefined`. What does `data` show if you print it out?

Comment: it shows correct data as my spreadsheet, but does't work.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mention, error reading 7 suggest an issue with

```
  var courseCol = data[i][7]
```

If it says error reading properties of undefined it means `data[i]` for that is undefined.

I would guess the issue is

```
for(var i=2; i <= lr; i++) {
```

Likely want

```
for(var i=2; i < lr; i++) {
```

Since I think `getLastRow` returns sheet position which is 1 based. JS arrays are 0 based.

so [1,2,3] are at positions [1,2,3] in excel / google sheets, but position [0,1,2] in js.

Comment: I just adjust as   for(var i=1; i<lr; i++) and print it out, the data show correctly, but doesn't work.